# RPC in Google Protobuf services

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Can a single protobuf service definition have more than one rpc calls defined?

```
service HelloService {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
  rpc SayHello2 (HelloRequest2) returns (HelloResponse2);
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest3) returns (HelloResponse3);
}
```

The protobuf definitions don't specify it anywhere but seems like all examples have just one.

Comment: Note that there is no argument overloading. You can't repeat SayHello twice, but you can have SayHello and SayHello2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly enough, a clear statement is missing in the `Defining Services` section of `protobuf` documentation, but the following example is taken from [`grpc`](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/java.html) documentation, which clearly answers your question:

```
// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  // Sends another greeting
  rpc SayHelloAgain (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}
```

Comment: Also, the example code in the [grpc github repository](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.11.x/examples/protos/route_guide.proto) shows proto files with multiple messages within a single service.